# Getting the image file into the file field while updating record

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
$Id=$_GET['edit'];
//Get Form Data from Data base against the Id
$Edit_Query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$Id'";
$Result=mysql_query($Edit_Query);    
while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {
        $Id=$Row['id'];
        $Product_Name=$Row['product_name'];
        $Product_Price=$Row['price'];
        $Product_Details=$Row['details'];
        $Category=$Row['category'];
        $Subcategory=$Row['subcategory'];
        $File_Name=$Row['product_picture']; 
    }
```

Now I echoed all variable into my input fields...
Please note that `['product_picture']` is the file name only ... physical file is uploaded in to my uploads folder...
Now i want to get that physical file automatically into my file field...so if user just change other fields and hit update button ... it will update the rest of the record and file should be remained as it is in the folder as well as db with that particular `$ID`.

I tried `<input type="file" name="product_picture" value="<php echo $File_Name; ?>">`
but it is not even echoing the file name....

In simple words its like User want to update the record but its not necessary that he must have to update the file too.... it should be on choice ..

Comment: The input file it just readonly, you can put a `<div>filename</div>` above that input file

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use a hidden field to store the image ID in,

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="image_id">
```

Then you can use it to assign the new image the previous ID and not have to update the SQL database.

Comment: You mean i have to make some other script for changing uploaded file ?

Comment: Well, if im right in understanding that you want an "update info" form to have all the fields filled out, so people can just change it. Then it can't be done with the file input

Comment: Changed me answer, i may have misunderstood the question

Comment: like in many sites you edit your profile ... but they give you optional to update profile pic or leave it as it is

Comment: they answer you give will skip my validation... i validated that the file field should not be empty.....

Comment: i think this would be done by setting a different file for change picture

Comment: What you want is not possible, sorry